# Using OpenId Connect with Azure AD then impersonate an existing Identity User

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I'm adding Azure AD authentication to an existing MVC application where it uses OWIN Identity for authenticating users from an SQL database.

The Database users are used in complex business with specific rules to manage certain parts of the application.

I have implemented OpenId Connect with Azure and was able to sign in but I need to map the AD authenticated user with the Identity that already exists then impersonate this identity to sign in with..

I made this Controller that I redirect to once the AD authentication succeeds:

Now the application does redirect but the identity stays the one from AD not the Identity one.

What is wrong with this code? how can I fix it?

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //The AD Name Identity is the user email
                var email = User.Identity.Name;

                //Get the user from Identity Provider
                var user = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Email == email);

                if(user!= null)
                {
                    //Sign In and Authenticate User
                    var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

                    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

                    var authenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
                    };

                    var app = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<AppBuilderProvider>().Get();
                    app.UseCookieAuthentication(authenticationOptions);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to associate or link the AD account with the local account, review the default ASP.net identity code in a new web project. It tracks and manages users with a local account and as many external accounts as you want. This should get you going in the right direction if not solve the issue for you.

However, if you want to impersonate a different user that is logged in (for debugging, for instance), that's for you to implement.

Here's a way: When you authenticate with an external provider the user is redirected back to your controller (to an action usually in AccountController called external login or something).

This action, by default, will Sign the user in with claims information from the external provider.

At this point you have a choice to make how you want to implement "impersonation."

•You could allow the user, based on permissions to impersonate another user by signing them out and sign them in as the selected user.
•You can store the impersonation userid as a session variable of sorts and check for that as the user (returning the actual user if it doesn't exist)

How you implement impersonation is up to you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply.. I'm looking for the 1st approach you mentioned because at the end what I want to do is to wire the 2 sources AD and local accounts, the idea is simply if an AD user is authenticated and this AD user already exists locally then I want to see his entities, profile, data..etc..

Is there a code sample I can refer to ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony, I was able to do it with the help of your instructions. This was the missing piece of the puzzle, I just copied the External Login mechanism from a new MVC project template and it worked just like expected.